# Python sum dataframe column in batches

Tags: python, sum

I have a 100 rows `DataFrame` and I would like to sum together every X rows from some column.

I tried to using rolling and cumsum but it does not helped me.

lets say this is my column:

```py
np.arange(1,100)
```

What I am trying to do is to sum the numbers from 1 to 10, 11 to 20 and so on (just example when X=10).

Any other solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: With no data and no code, this question cannot be answered here...

Comment: It is just a column of numbers. I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that your index is an auto-increment starting at 0, you could do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(1,100)})
batch_size = 10
df.groupby((df.index // batch_size).rename('group_number')).a.sum().reset_index()
```

This outputs the following dataframe:

```
   group_number    a
0             0   55
1             1  155
2             2  255
3             3  355
4             4  455
5             5  555
6             6  655
7             7  755
8             8  855
9             9  855
```

the grouping is done by the expression `df.index // batch_size`, which will split all, except perhaps the last group of rows into groups of consecutive rows of size `batch_size`. The last group may have fewer than `batch_size` rows.

we know that

- the sum of all integers between 1 & 10 is 55, `(1 + 10) * (10 / 2)`
- the sum of all integers between 11 & 20 is 155, `(11 + 20) * (10 / 2)`
- the other group-sums also check out with the Gauss's Summation Technique.

so my solution seems to checkout.